# 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal collection view working as a pager of 4 screens/steps. I disabled the horizontal scrolling as a way to perform next action only from a floating button:

```
let nextItem = self.selectedIndexPath.item + 1
self.scrollToStep(index: IndexPath(item: nextItem, section: 0))

func scrollToStep(index: IndexPath){
   selectedIndexPath = index
   collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)  
}
```

The second time I tap the button the app crashes.

> ] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid
>   index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001088dd6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000107e81ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001088dd555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197     3   UIKitCore
>   0x000000010b79ef93 -[UICollectionView
>   _contentOffsetForScrollingToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 212  4   UIKitCore                           0x000000010b79f86b
>   -[UICollectionView _scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 70  5                       0x0000000105238770
>   $s14 18ViewControllerC12scrollToStep5indexy10Foundation9IndexPathV_tF
>   + 480     6                        0x00000001052358b5 $s1 ar 010collectionF0_13cellForItemAtSo012UICollectionF4CellCSo0mF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFySbcfU_
>   + 1701

Comment: Could you add more code for the collectionview population?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*4 screens/steps* are represented by the indices 0 - 3. The error clearly states an out-of-range error.

You have to check if `nextItem` reaches the end index

```
let nextItem = self.selectedIndexPath.item + 1
if nextItem < 4 {
   self.scrollToStep(index: IndexPath(item: nextItem, section: 0))
}
```

Comment: I changed it to 3 instead of 4, but the same error.

Comment: 4 is correct because the index is incremented before the check. Actually this code must not crash.

Comment: But it does crash after the second step.

Answer (score 2):

```
var staticIndex = 0
```

in button click action

```
if staticIndex < 3 {
    var indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: staticIndex+1, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
    staticIndex += 1
}
```